# Transforming columns of a dataframe in Python similar to dplyr in R

Tags: python, r, pandas

Is it possible to use different transformations on different columns of a dataframe without multiple assignments with repetition of the dataframe name in Python? For example consider the below code:

```py
df['col1'] = f_1(df['col1'])
df['col2'] = f_2(df['col2'])
df['col3'] = f_3(df['col3'])
```

you can think of f_i() as any arbitrary transformation such as "pd.to_datetime()". Note that I had to repeat "df[]" 6 times. The same thing is trivial in R (using dplyr package) and one can simply do it as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)

df = df |>
     mutate(col1 = f_1(col1),
            col2 = f_2(col2),
            col3 = f_3(col3))
```

you can then continue with the Pipe operations (|>) and do a lot more stuff with the transformed variables without the need to mention "df[]" again and again. Is such an approach possible in Python as well?

Comment: you can use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

Comment: @Stef but even with assing you still need to either use df.assign(col1 = f_1(df['col1'])) or df.assign(col1 = lambda x: f_1(x.col1)), ain't that true? The df doesn't flow inside assign.

Comment: yes, it's just that you can make all three columns in one call to assign, but on the right hand side you still need to write df['col1'] etc.